# is it the samongod or brew services start mongodb-community@4.0 to start mongoDB server?

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I am new to mongodb.  I am using [the installation guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#install-mongodb-community-edition) to install `MongoDB 4.0 community edition`.  After the installation, I used `brew services start mongodb-community@4.0` to run MongoDB.  To cleanly shurtdown the server, I started a mongo shell, and ran `use admin` and `db.shutdown.Server()`.

Next, to start the server again, I ran `brew services start mongodb-community@4.0` and got

```
`Service `mongodb-community` already started, use `brew services restart mongodb-community` to restart.`
```

So I did `brew services restart mongodb-community@4.0` and got the returned msg below:

```
Stopping `mongodb-community`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)
```

My question: 
(1) Is running `brew services start mongodb-community@4.0` the same as running `mongod`?
(2) Why does it say `Service`mongodb-community`already started` when I start the server again? Did I not cleanly shutdown the server?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have 2 options. Either run it as a service like application (your first option). Or run it from the command line (your second option). So depending on your needs you can do either one.

Refering to the document. If you have used: brew install mongodb-community@4.0

The log and database folders are already created.